# JavaScript error using latest lightbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, lightbox, lightbox2

First of all, I'm not good with JavaScript at all. I followed all instructions on this page:
http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Visually everything loads fine. However, visual studio throws this error while running. If I hit continue everything seems to be loading fine. I see all buttons, animation, etc. I can only guess that something not loading properly. But not sure..

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think i had the same problem as this. In the end I decided to go with this version of a different lightbox instead as it works like a jQuery plugin http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: @Tim - Put your comment as an answer - This is what I did and it works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i had the same problem as this. In the end I decided to go with this version of a different lightbox instead as it works like a jQuery plugin

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

For me I felt it was a lot nicer since it worked with jQuery as a Plugin, and didnt rely on the 6 js files!